# Retrieve the data based on date column, date column is having null and not null values

Tags: sql, db2, db2-luw, maximo

I'm trying to retrieve the change request details from db2 based on actual finish date and status, where ever the actual finish date is `null` is not getting retrieve the status, how can come up

My where condition:

```
WHERE
    OWNER LIKE '%abc%'
    AND  ACTFINISH BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-28 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Note that you don't want to use `BETWEEN` [with date/time/timestamp types](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common) (this applies to pretty much all RDBMSs - and timestamps in LUW can have varying fractional seconds anyways).  Or pretty much anything that isn't an explicit Integer count, really (logically, there's always a further fractional portion involved).

Comment: Hi Muse, Thanks for your response, even if i use >= and <= operands on date column, still I didn't get full data, as the some of date column having null, so I want to retrieve those null values data as well on date time column condition

Answer (score 4):

Whenever you apply any comparison to a `null` value (including between) it will evaluate to unknown (which is not `true`), and thus not return the row this condition was applied on. You'd have to explicitly handle `null` yourself:

```
WHERE owner LIKE '%abc%' AND 
      (actfinish IS NULL OR 
       actfinish BETWEEN '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-28 23:59:59'
      )
```

Comment: Thanks you Mureinik, for suggesting and from side I done with the below condition (OWNER LIKE '%@abc%') AND (ACTFINISH '2014-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2014-02-28 23:59:59' OR ACTFINISH IS NULL))
AND  STATUS IN ('CLOSE','CAN')